# Laravel y Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, vite

tengo un proyecto en laravel9 y lo estoy migrando a docker, ya lo configure e instale las dependencias pero estoy teniendo un problema con los estilos de ccs con vite, ejecuto el comando npm run dev

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al parecer todo bien pero al entrar en la web no se cargan los estilos css, inspeccione la pagina y esto es lo que esta en el head

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

supongo que el problema esta con algo en el docker ya que en local funciona bien, informándome encontré que cuando se trabaja desde un servidor remoto hay que pasar la ip de este al vite para que te lo genere de la siguiente forma: "npm run dev -- --host 192.168.100.100" pero esto tampoco da resultado en el docker

**configuración del docker-compose:**

```
version: '2.2'

services:
 web:
  container_name: web
  restart: always
  build: ./.docker
  ports:
   - 8080:80
   - 5173:5173
  networks:
   - overlay
  volumes:
   - /home/www-data/web/:/var/www/html/web
   - ./.docker/http/vhost.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
volumes:
 mariadb-data:
networks:
 overlay:
```

Comment: Tienes que exponer todos los puertos que necesitas del contenedor. Cómo está iniciando? Cómo se ejecuta el `docker run` del contenedor?

Comment: se configuro con docker-compose up -d --build y ya se esta exponiendo el puerto pero sigue sin funcionar los estilos

Comment: No es por no creerte pero, por qué no vas a [edit] y _muestras_ lo que nos estás contando en el comentario? Así no se trata de creerte sino de que probemos entre todos lo que tú estás haciendo :)

Comment: vale ya modifico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se resolvió agregando un segmento de código al archivo vite.config.js justo después de la linea que dice "export default defineConfig({"

```
server: {
    host: true,
    hmr: {
        host: 'tu ip'
    }
},
```